# Getter and Setter for desktop position

Tags: powershell, scripting, file-management

for quite some time I've been wanting a method to have more desktops in windows11, one for each context I need, but it seems there is no official way

For now I just associate the files of a context to the relative folder, and then move them in and out of desktop

I've come to realize that i REALLY like for all files to be in the exact position I left them. It helps a lot with getting in the flux.

What I wanted was the following 2 scripts:

desktop_position_get: name -> position

desktop_position_set: name, position -> X

After some tweak, this is the getter script I came up with the help of GPT4:

```
$desktopPath = [Environment]::GetFolderPath("Desktop")
$itemName = "target_file.ext"

$shell = New-Object -ComObject "Shell.Application"
$desktopFolder = $shell.Namespace($desktopPath)
$desktopItems = $desktopFolder.Items()

$itemIndex = $desktopItems | Get-Member -MemberType Properties | Where-Object { $_.Name -eq "Name" } | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Definition | Select-String -Pattern "$itemName" | Select-Object -ExpandProperty LineNumber

if ($itemIndex) {
    $item = $desktopItems.Item($itemIndex - 1)
    $position = $desktopFolder.GetDetailsOf($item, 31)
    $col = [int]$position
    Write-Host "$col"
}
else {
    Write-Host "-1"
}
```

It never seems to work, though. I've googled for a solution on multiple occasions, but I couldn't find what I needed. Does anyone know how to fix this?